Function not found error in spring boot lambda function when execute sam local invoke command
I've a spring boot lambda function which process the SQSEvents. This lambda function is deployed in AWS and its working fine, i am trying to execute the lambda in my local using sam local invoke, I have defined the teamplate.yaml and event.json file. When i execute the sam local invoke, the logs shows lambda started and then it shows the error

No function defined

 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)
2024-06-03 11:52:03.919  INFO 16 --- [           main] lambdainternal.AWSLambda                 : Starting AWSLambda on a48c97625309 with PID 16 (/var/runtime/lib/aws-lambda-java-runtime-0.2.0.jar started by root in /var/task)
2024-06-03 11:52:03.921  INFO 16 --- [           main] lambdainternal.AWSLambda                 : The following profiles are active: default        
2024-06-03 11:52:08.151  INFO 16 --- [           main] lambdainternal.AWSLambda                 : Started AWSLambda in 7.047 seconds (JVM running for 9.109)
Started
No function defined: java.lang.IllegalStateException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No function defined
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.apply(AbstractSpringFunctionAdapterInitializer.java:183)
        at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(SpringBootRequestHandler.java:51)

END RequestId: 535d54d9-8d9e-45f7-86fe-fbd3178c54db

Below is my main class:
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.helloworld")
public class HelloLambdaSqsApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HelloLambdaSqsApplication.class, args);
  }
}

Handler class:
public class HelloLambdaSqsFunctionHandler extends SpringBootRequestHandler<SQSEvent, String>  {

}

Below is lambda function :
@Component("helloLambdaSqsFunction")
public class HelloLambdaSqsFunction implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, String> {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {
        event.getRecords().forEach(message -> {
            String userId = message.getBody();  // Assuming the message body contains the userId
            UserDto user = userService.getUserById(userId);
            System.out.println("Username: " + user.getUserName());
        });
        return "Processed " + event.getRecords().size() + " records.";
    }
}

Template.yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: |
  AWS SAM Template for Hello World Lambda function triggered by SQS.

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ../lambda/HelloWorldFunction          
      Handler: com.example.helloworld.HelloLambdaSqsFunctionHandler          
      Runtime: java11
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 30
      Environment:
        Variables:
          SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: default
      Events:
        SQSEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: !GetAtt HelloWorldQueue.Arn

  HelloWorldQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: MyQueue

Outputs:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: Hello World Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldQueue:
    Description: Hello World SQS Queue URL
    Value: !Ref HelloWorldQueue

my project structure:
sam-test/
│
├── lambda/
│   ├── HelloWorldFunction/
│       ├── src/
│           ├── main/
│               ├── java/
│                   ├── com.example.helloworld/
│                       ├── service/
│                           ├── UserService
│                       ├── HelloLambdaSqsApplication.java
│                       ├── HelloLambdaSqsFunction.java
│                       ├── HelloLambdaSqsFunctionHandler.java
│       ├── pom.xml
├── sam/
│   ├── samconfig/
│       ├── event.json   # The event file for local testing     
│       ├── env.json                                
│   ├── template.yaml    # Your SAM template                    
└── README.md

Can someone help me on this?
